# Why am I getting "no tests to run" despite having a test function?

Tags: go, testing

Go newbie here, I have written a simple main_test.go file to run some test cases for main.go, when I run `go test` it says testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
ok      Solution    0.878s

my main.go:

```
package main

func normalizePhoneNum(phoneNumber string) string {
    return ""
}

func main() {

}
```

main_test.go:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func testNormalizePhoneNum(t *testing.T) {
    testCase := []struct {
        input  string
        output string
    }{
        {"1234567890", "1234567890"},
        {"123 456 7891", "123 456 7891"},
        {"(123) 456 7892", "(123) 456 7892"},
        {"(123) 456-7893", "(123) 456-7893"},
        {"123-456-7894", "123-456-7894"},
        {"123-456-7890", "123-456-7890"},
        {"1234567892", "1234567892"},
        {"(123)456-7892", "(123)456-7892"},
    }
    for _, tc := range testCase {
        t.Run(tc.input, func(t *testing.T) {
            actual := normalizePhoneNum(tc.input)
            if actual != tc.output {
                t.Errorf("for %s: got %s, expected %s", tc.input, actual, tc.output)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell, why it's not running the test cases?

Answer (score 31):

Elementary! See the [documentation for the `go test` command](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go/internal/test):

> A test function is one named `TestXxx` (where `Xxx` does not start with a lower case letter) and should have the signature,
>
> ```
> func TestXxx(t *testing.T) { ... }
> ```

Note that **the first letter must be an uppercase `T`**. You must respect this naming convention for test functions or the testing tool will simply ignore them.

Rename your test function to `TestNormalizePhoneNum` and try running `go test` again.

---

Alternatively—and although that is most likely **not** what you want here—you can force the testing tool to run a "test function" that doesn't adhere to the naming convention by specifying its name (or, more generally, a regular expression that its name matches) in the `-run` flag:

```
go test -run=testNormalizePhoneNum
```

Comment: also please have a look at golang documentation https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/add-a-test